# Do ephemeral port numbers run in sequence for the whole system, per process or per listening port?

Tags: linux, windows, port, tcp

We have an application and we use the ephemeral port number to identify the connection. We listen on two different ports, one for normal connections and one for SSL connections. I want to avoid the situation where the port numbers clash because the OS is assigning the ephemeral port numbers per listening port instead of per process or across the system as whole.

We are hosting on Windows but would like the option to switch to linux at some stage.

Comment: You should probably use the full 5-tuple of *IP source address, IP destination address, protocol, source port and destination port* if you actually want to reliably identify a connection.

Comment: Because we own the app and its code, the destination IP and port are always the same and just extra noise.

Comment: You are using two different destination ports. If you discard that information, then you will naturally have clashes. Destination port is not "just extra noise" here.

Comment: Sorry what I mean to say is that in our code each port is isolated and the collection that we are using to store the connections will be full of connections with the same port number, therefore not offering any more information that we don't already know.

Comment: You need to change your application to match the OS requirements. In this case, since you are using two different destination ports in the app, you need to use that as a key inside the app. You are creating too complex a system if you try to drop the destination port.